# storing a pgfpoint for repeated use

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to pgf and am trying to create my own shape. Since in a lot of the path commands I reuse the same point (`\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}`), I am wondering what is the best point to store the point, so that I can change the point from one place.

What is the recommended way to do this? Can the `\pgf@registers` be reused after saving the point? Are there savemethods that optimize this? I.e. there is `\pgfqpoint` which seems to do simpler input parsing, is there a way to do something like the following:

```
\savepoint{myName}{\pgfpoint{2cm+1pt}{3ex}}
\pgfpathlineto{\myname} %compute cost here equivalent to the cost of \pgfqpoint at most
\pgfpathlineto{\myname} %compute cost here equivalent to the cost of \pgfqpoint at most
```

Does saving a point work with `def` or are there other recommended methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an internal command `\pgfextract@process` which does what you want:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfextract@process\startpoint{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfextract@process\endpoint{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{10pt}{20pt}}%
    {\pgfpoint{20pt}{0pt}}}
\show\startpoint
\show\endpoint
```

Which will produce in the log file something like:

```
> \startpoint=macro:
->\pgf@x =0.0pt\relax \pgf@y =0.0pt\relax .
l.7 \show\startpoint

> \endpoint=macro:
->\pgf@x =30.0pt\relax \pgf@y =20.0pt\relax .
l.8 \show\endpoint
```

`\pgfextract@process` processes its second argument inside a `TeX` group and then takes `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` outside the group by making them global. The values of `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` are then saved in the macro name given as the the first argument.